# ООП, наследование классов, проблема с переменной

Tags: python, ооп, global-variables

У меня есть недоработанная программа. Я хочу сделать, чтобы при создании нового объекта класса `Alive` этому объекту присваивался `ID`, увеличенный на единицу. Я представляю эту реализацию через глобальную переменную, на моём примере `totalId = -1`. Но мне выводит ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
>     invoker = Hero("Invoker")
>   File "test.py", line 14, in __init__
>     Alive.__init__(self)
>   File "test.py", line 9, in __init__
>     self.id = totalId + 1
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totalId' referenced before assignment
> ```

Я также пробовал делать эту переменную `global` в разных местах, но всё равно выводит схожую ошибку. Как мне надо устроить данную переменную, чтобы она могла изменяться в дочерних классах `Alive`?

```
import random

totalId = -1

class Alive:
    def __init__(self):
        teams = ["Honor", "BlackLoop"]
        self.team = random.choice(teams)
        self.id = totalId + 1
        totalId = totalId + 1

class Hero(Alive):
    def __init__(self, name = "default", lvl = 1):
        Alive.__init__(self)
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.name = name

    def lvlUp(self, count = 1):
        self.lvl = self.lvl + count

    def getInfo(self):
        print(f"{'*' * 20}\nId_{self.id}\nName: {self.name}\nTeam: {self.team}\nLevel: {self.lvl}\n{'*' * 20}\n\n")

class Soldier(Alive):
    def followTheHero(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    honor = []
    blackloop = []

    invoker = Hero("Invoker")
    void = Hero("Void")

    invoker.getInfo()
    void.getInfo()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь вовсе не стоит использовать глобальную переменную. Вообще, почти всегда использовать вместе глобальные переменные и полноценное ооп с иерархией классов - это плохая идея. Глобальные переменные уместны только в простых скриптах.

В вашем случае переменная `totalId` используется внутри класса, соответственно и определять её надо как атрибут класса.

И ещё - стандартные рекомендации по именованию переменных рекомендуют не использовать заглавную `I` в одном имени вместе с маленькими буквами - её очень легко спутать с `l`. И вообще - заглавные буквы стоит использовать только для имён классов и констант.

```
class Alive:

    total_id = -1

    def __init__(self):
        teams = ["Honor", "BlackLoop"]
        self.team = random.choice(teams)
        Alive.total_id += 1
        self.id = Alive.total_id
```

Comment: Благодарю, Ваш ответ мне сильно помог!

Answer (score 2):

Переменная `totalId` на уровне *модуля* нет та самая, что *локальная* переменная `totalId` в методе `__init__()`, когда она не определена в этом методе как `global`.

```
class Alive:
    def __init__(self):
        global totalId                       ##### нужно добавить #####
        teams = ["Honor", "BlackLoop"]
        self.team = random.choice(teams)
        self.id = totalId + 1
        totalId = totalId + 1
```